# How an ERC721 contract can be sold on multiple markets?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, markets

I'm trying to build an NFT market where you can put your existing ERC721 contract tokens on sale. My workflow is like this:

1. Token owner comes to marketplace, puts a token to sale by giving the `contractAddress`, `tokenId` and `price` as parameters.
2. Frontend calls the owner to call `approve` method of the ERC721 contract to mark marketplace contract as `operator`.
3. When a `buy` method is called from a customer, the marketplace contract transfers the token to the new owner by calling `safeTransferFrom` of the ERC721 contract, and transfers the money to the old owner.

This workflow is ok for me, but when I inspect [ERC721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) I see that the `operator` can call `safeTransferFrom` method which changes the owner of the token. Also, `getApproved` method is returning only **one address**. So if the owner of the token uses some other marketplace contract and changes the `operator` to another contract, my marketplace contract will lose its ability to call `safeTransferFrom` method and sales will not work.

My questions are these:

1. Are the NFT's can be sold only in one marketplace at the same time?
2. Is my workflow wrong? Is it somehow different from how NFT marketplace contracts work?
3. How do other marketplaces handle this only one operator issue?